# install 64bit software on debian 2.6.32-5-amd6

Tags: mongodb, debian, x86-64

I've got strange problem.
I try to install 64bit MongoDB on my server with Debian 6.0.1a but i failed. 
Seems like something wrong with my OS.

```
uname -a
Linux db 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 8 22:49:26 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

looks like it's ok but when I try to install something 64 bit i've got

```
dpkg -i mongodb-server_1.4.4-3_amd64.deb 
dpkg: error processing mongodb-server_1.4.4-3_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-server_1.4.4-3_amd64.deb
```

and also error trying to launch binaries

```
./mongod
bash: ./mongod: No such file or directory
```

What did i do incorrect?

Comment: To me it looks like you have something funny going on with your system, I would ask somewhere a bit more Debian specific where someone would maybe have the time to look at your system and figure out why it is having an identity crisis.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct, but i think it's better to use apt :

[Install MongoDB on Debian](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

Comment: A did apt-get install mongodb20-10gen and it's started to download  mongodb20-10gen i386 2.0.8. What's wrong? Where is my 64 bit?

Comment: i apologize i was wrong. It was successful installed using apt! Thank you so much.